# How android decides the dimention of button during designing time

Tags: android, nine-patch

**`I designed a button using photoshop, size of button is`**

- width=112
- height=50

**That button contains a icon and some text**

- I saved this button as `png` and then using ANDROID asset
  generator(9-patch,website)

**I generated button for xhdpi,hdpi,mdpi,xxhdpi
The dimention of**::

- hdpi button is=`86*40`
- mdpi=`58*27`

[image]

---

- when i am designing the application in the designing layout, i set
  image button with an height to `wrap-content`
- what happening is, in the designing layout, size of the button is
  bigger than original size in `hdpi`
- I set the screen size `4.0'' Wvga (480*800) hdpi`

---

**What i am not able to understand**::

1. Why when i set `wrap-content` for both height & width, why it is
   bigger than original dimension of `hdpi button`
2. Can i set the original `hdpi dimention(86*40)` for the button, or else
   i need to set the  `wrap-content` ?
3. How is the default image dimention is selected by android -  is it based
   on screen-resolution .. or API ? `(I am using 14-api)`

---

Comment: Why are you using 9 patches?

Comment: @ Artoo Detoo ........... Since android automatically resize the image automatically based on screen size... I am using it !

Comment: Yes. AND it's NOT the proper use case.

Comment: @ Artoo Detoo ..... So if i have a button with icon background ...... we should not use 9-patches ? .... im confused with this context .... !

Comment: No. Normally 9 pngs are used for doing frames or such or when hardly scaling an object (it could be the case of a Spinner graphics, a border). In your case it seems that you can manage it better with normal SCALED graphics (each drawable folder containing the graphics for that resolution). See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)